# Wrong type inference when using Zod

Tags: typescript, validation, zod

In this validation schema, if the validation passes, the type of `email` will always be a `string`. However, for some reason typescript is telling me that `email` either returns a `string` or `false`. I do not see any possibility that `email` could ever return `false`, am I missing something?

**To elaborate:** When I use z.string().email(), I am guaranteeing that the outcome is indeed a valid email, otherwise the validation will fail and the value will not be passed to the transform > normalizeEmail part. So the final result must indeed be an `string`.

```
import { z } from "zod";
import validator from "validator";

const email = (maxChar: number) =>
  z
    .string()
    .max(maxChar)
    .email().transform((value) => validator.normalizeEmail(value))
    ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`validator.normalizeEmail` returns `false` if the email is not valid (which is a strange design choice if you ask me). Since you are already checking if it is a valid email using Zod, I would opt for an [assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
const email = (maxChar: number) =>
  z
    .string()
    .max(maxChar)
    .email().transform((value) => validator.normalizeEmail(value) as string)
    ;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcBEyEAJvgNwCwAUKJLHAG4CGANsMUzNFjnvs2w5co5atQDGEAHYBneAFMQTYCzgBeOAAolADwDCACyZQAXHCkBXEACN5UAJTqAfNTgpXbuADo5UYFIBzTXsPNy9dbSZ9IwdQ70VlFmCvGCgmWUxoEE1NAQt5RzUnRlZ2TmgvKSzS5HkAUSUVXNZ8xyYZOF9-AJCqTzgyIA)

Comment: thanks @katniss, I thought it is a pretty strange design too. Goes against my OCD but seems like I have to do the type assertion here!